# Intervals of integers modulo n

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request, notation, modular-arithmetic

Do the following related concepts appear anywhere in literature?

1. Denoting an "interval" in the integers modulo $n$ by $[i,j] = \{i, i+1, \dotsc, j\}$. For example, in modulo 6, $[5,3] = \{5,0,1,2,3\}$.
2. Given a collection of intervals $\mathcal{I}$ (e.g. of the above type, or of real numbers), is there a name for the property that for every pair of intersecting intervals $I$ and $J$ in $\mathcal{I}$, either $I \subseteq J$ or $J \subseteq I$?

Answer (score 1):

For 2, if the collection is finite, then you can consider its [interval graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_graph), which is a graph representation of the intersections among the intervals in the collection. Now I quote Wikipedia:

> The interval graphs that have an interval representation in which every two intervals are either disjoint or nested are the [trivially perfect graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivially_perfect_graph).

Comment: Sorry, I realised that wasn't exactly what I was asking - I have corrected the question.

Comment: Now that works, thank you!

Comment: Actually, one could say that $\mathcal{I}$ is a nested collection of intervals. From the same wikipedia page you linked, "A set of intervals is nested if, for every two intervals in the set, either the two are disjoint or one contains the other."